# Find the new equation of pair of straight lines

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations

Equation of pair of straight lines is
$$7x^2+4xy+4y^2=0$$ 
What will be new equation of straight lines if the coordinate axes become the angle-bisector of above two lines.

My Try:

$$7x^2+4xy+4y^2=0$$
$$4\left(\frac yx\right)^2+4\left(\frac yx\right)+7=0$$ 
Solving above quadratic equation for $y/x$ we get
$$\frac yx=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{4^2-4\cdot4\cdot 7}}{2\cdot 4}$$
$$\frac yx=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{6}}{2}$$
I get imaginary roots of above equation which doesn't represent a pair of real straight lines. I do not know where is my mistake. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Do you mean lines in $\Bbb C^2$, or lines in $\Bbb R^2$? Because in $\Bbb R^2$ this is just an equation for the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: I think the question you have come across is wrong. The equation you're getting is correct. This cannot be solved to obtain a pair of straight lines. [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0rkrvec6sq) only plots the origin as the intersection of the lines with the real plane.

Comment: That's not a pair of lines. Those never have a nonzero cross-term.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the equation 
$$
7x^2+4xy+4y^2=0
$$
does not represent a pair of straight line in $\mathbb R$, but just a point.

Infact you can write:
\begin{gather}
7x^2+4xy+4y^2=0\\
\left(\sqrt 7 x + \frac{2}{\sqrt 7}y\right)^2 + \left(2\frac{\sqrt 6}{\sqrt 7} y\right)^2 = 0
\end{gather}
And only the point $(0,0)$ satisfies this equation.

---

Your argument in infact correct when $x\neq 0$ and the result is coherent: there are no points in $\mathbb R^2\ \backslash \ \{(0,0)\}$ that satisfies the equation.